# Spring Boot: web-app + webservice

Tags: java, rest, jsp, spring-boot

Need to create a webapp in java using spring boot which has UI and also it functions as a webservice. (web-app + webservice using spring boot). How to do the configurations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the SpringBoot example that is most close to your problem space and extend.  You can find the samples [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples).

Alternatively you can use the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/)

Comment: Using two controllers one with  annotation Controller for web and another as annotation RestController. And adding anno EnableWebMVC

Answer (score 1):

I think that this question is a bit wide. You should start by reading some tutorial like :

http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

I don't really know a good option to do UI with spring boot, but maybe look at :

https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/

You will need to learn and read a bit but I hope it helped you :)

EmCode

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of Web app from the original spring page:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

And this for webservices

https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/

You only need to start from the first example and add configuration in the 2nd